# How to build NativeScript project for IOS on Windows?

Tags: ios, windows, nativescript

Please dont tell me about the licence issue.

I just want to be able to test my code in both environements (Android/IOS) at the same time.

I am not interested in the Virtualisation of IOS because its very slow.

Answer (score 5):

Nativescript-sidekick will do it for you on the cloud ... and for free.

> With NativeScript Sidekick you can leave SDK management to us,
>   literally. You simply tell Sidekick to build your app in our cloud and
>   we will deliver you the IPA and/or APK app package back to you. Your
>   NativeScript assets are secure in their delivery to our cloud servers.

[Develop iOS apps on Windows with nativescript-sidekick](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/develop-ios-apps-on-windows-with-nativescript-sidekick)

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong but, sidekick only builds using cloud services, it doesn't provide you with an emulator

Answer (score 3):

As XCode can't be run on Windows and you don't want to virtualize, you have one option left, you can let someone else do the builds for you. For NativeScript, you can get a seamless experience with the Telerik Platform:  http://www.telerik.com/platform#overview

There are of course many other mac cloud services (such as CloudBees, MacinCloud, MacBuildServer, Unity Cloud and many others). However, for NativeScript, I'd strongly suggest looking at the Telerik Platform as it's a tool made just for that.

Comment: It should be pointed out there are a couple of problems with the Telerik Platform. Firstly, you cannot run unit tests on the Telerik Platform. But more critically, a lot of npm modules you use will cause your app to not compile and you end up having to disable those modules, or having to re-build a package file each time to run on iOS in the companion app. Even then, a lot of npm modules still will not work. It is a problem being addressed by the Telerik team and on their AppBuilder platform.