# Is there any way to build IOS app on Windows?

Tags: ios, react-native, nativescript

I'm developing native apps but I have a Windows pc. Is there an actual way to build iOS apps on Windows? And can I run an ios emulator on Windows? I researched but I can't find an actual way.

I tried to install MacOS Sierra on Virtual Box but it consistently restarting.

Do I need both to build it?

Comment: You can use a virtual machine to achieve that, but directly from windows OS no.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to build NativeScript project for IOS on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35116965/how-to-build-nativescript-project-for-ios-on-windows)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

NativeScript CLI & Sidekick support cloud build that would help you build your app from a Windows machine, basically the source code is uploaded to a remote machine and built there, then you could directly run the package on your local iOS device.

But unfortunately it is not possible to run the iOS Simulator on Windows at all, which is a limitation from Apple.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used it before, but apparently you can do so using [Nativescript Sidekick](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/develop-ios-apps-on-windows-with-nativescript-sidekick).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will try it and share the reason with you.

Comment: Only if you use cloud builds.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, flutter is the key to do it, 
But I don't recommend it because its still in beta state  and to implement it you need to learn a new language i.e dart which feels similar to Java at start but is actually very different also you won find any book or tutorials. 
While their is 1 more solution 
You can download McOs virtual machine but it would be very slow, recommended only if you have a powerful computer

Comment: I don't think even with Flutter you can actually run the app on Windows as iOS simulator comes with only Xcode & Mac. As you mentioned VirtualBox could be an option but will be super slow.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53381061/can-flutter-remove-the-need-for-a-mac-to-create-ios-apps/53381182#53381182